# Bad Symbolic reference to reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericHandlers encountered in class file 'JSONGenericHandlers.class'

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework-2.3, reactivemongo

I'm having my apis in play 2.3 with reactive mongo. Recently, i tried to cleaned the  project and during the process, some things got updated. Later, when i tried to run or compile that, i'm getting these errors. Apart from clean, i didn't do anything. Kindly help me.

```
[info] Compiling 48 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /home/Ruthvick/zcapi/zceapi    /target  /scala-2.11/classes...
[error] bad symbolic reference to reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericHandlers encountered in class file 'JSONGenericHandlers.class'.
 [error] Cannot access type GenericHandlers in package reactivemongo.api.collections. The current classpath may be
[error] missing a definition for reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericHandlers, or JSONGenericHandlers.class may have been compiled against a version that's
[error] incompatible with the one found on the current classpath.
[error] /home/Ruthvick/zcapi/zceapi/app/controllers/Application.scala:28: type arguments [play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONCollection] do not conform to method collection's type parameter bounds [C <: reactivemongo.api.Collection]
[error]     def collection: JSONCollection = db.collection[JSONCollection]("shoppage")
[error]                                                   ^
[error] /home/Ruthvick/zcapi/zceapi/app/controllers/Application.scala:47: could not find implicit value for parameter writer: GenericCollection.this.pack.Writer[play.api.libs.json.JsObject]
[error]             collection.insert(result).map { lastError =>
[error]                              ^

[error] 60 errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] application -
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of Play is not compatible with the newest Snapshot of Play Reactive Mongo. You could just use Version 0.10.5.

Add this to your Library Dependencies

```
"org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.10.5.0.akka23"
```